# Php - Add a counter at the beggin of every array_chunk and a text at the end

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I'm having trouble adding a counter at the beggin of every array_chunk and a text at the end.

Below is my actual code. I use the $txtcontent as text input from a webform.

```
        function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2)
    {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}



    $format = $_POST['format'];
    $titre= strtoupper($_POST['titre']);
    $txtcontent = $_POST['texte'];
    $txtcontent =  wordwrap($txtcontent,20,hexToStr('0D0A'),true);


$txtcontent = explode("\n", $txtcontent);
$input = array_chunk($txtcontent, 9, false);
foreach($input as $key => $array){
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        $input[$key][$k] = '\text '.($k*6+1).',1,'.$commas.str_replace(hexToStr('0D'), "", $v).$commas.hexToStr('0D0A');
    }
}
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
} 
$array = array_flatten($input);

$filecontent = implode($array);     

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$_POST['titre'].'.'.$format.'');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    //$fh = fopen($filename, 'wb');
    $fh = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
    fwrite($fh, $filecontent);
    fclose($fh);
```

I want add a counter at the beggin of every array_chunk and a text at the end.

Exemple:
if i sumbit this content as input in the webform:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line11
line12
line13
line14
line15
line16
line17
line18
line19
line20
```

I will have a file with this content:

```
\text 1,1,"line1"
\text 7,1,"line2"
\text 13,1,"line3"
\text 19,1,"line4"
\text 25,1,"line5"
\text 31,1,"line6"
\text 37,1,"line7"
\text 43,1,"line8"
\text 49,1,"line9"
\text 1,1,"line10"
\text 7,1,"line11"
\text 13,1,"line12"
\text 19,1,"line13"
\text 25,1,"line14"
\text 31,1,"line15"
\text 37,1,"line16"
\text 43,1,"line17"
\text 49,1,"line18"
\text 1,1,"line19"
\text 7,1,"line20"
```

However, i want have something like the code below. At the beginning of each chunk should be added the counter, like \If S=1, ... and at the end, the text \IfEnd

```
\If S=1
\text 1,1,"line1"
\text 7,1,"line2"
\text 13,1,"line3"
\text 19,1,"line4"
\text 25,1,"line5"
\text 31,1,"line6"
\text 37,1,"line7"
\text 43,1,"line8"
\text 49,1,"line9"
\IfEnd
\If S=2
\text 1,1,"line10"
\text 7,1,"line11"
\text 13,1,"line12"
\text 19,1,"line13"
\text 25,1,"line14"
\text 31,1,"line15"
\text 37,1,"line16"
\text 43,1,"line17"
\text 49,1,"line18"
\IfEnd
\If S=3
\text 1,1,"line19"
\text 7,1,"line20"
```

Note that the input can always be larger than 20 lines.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried putting the following code in place of your foreach loop, and ended up with the same output you described (minus the quotation marks):

```
$i = 1;
foreach($input as $key => $array){
    $j = 1;
    $input[$key][0] = "\If S=".$i."\n";
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        $input[$key][$k+1] = '\text '.($k*6+1).',1,'.$commas.str_replace(hexToStr('0D'), "", $v).$commas.hexToStr('0D0A');
        $j++;
    }
    if ($j == 10) $input[$key][10] = "\IfEnd\n";
    $i++;
}
```

I hope this helps.  Basically I added extra key-value pairs in your array to get an If and IfEnd for each iteration, and kept some counts.